# Аутентификация по собственной сгенерированной подписи

Tags: java, spring-security, аутентификация

У меня есть ТЗ на написание JSON API (Spring Security & MVC) с таким пунктом (в конце публикации)

После двух дней перечитывания документации по спринг секьюрити и прошерстив все ресурсы до которых могу дотянуться (догуглиться). Так до конца и не понял как это реализовать.

Может кто подскажет куда копать или подкинет какие то конкретные примеры?

> В каждом запросе пользователя к сервису должен присутствовать его
> уникальный идентификатор. Для аутентификации пользователя запросы к
> сервису должны подписываться подписью. Формирование подписи
> производится следующим образом:
>
> ###Условия формировании подписи###
>
> Итоговая последовательность хэшируется с помощью алгоритма SHA-1.
> Уникальный идентификатор и секретный ключ заранее известны пользователю (т.е. реализовывать регистрацию пользователя в системе не
> нужно)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: вам нужно добавить в проект свой `AuthenticationProvider`. Ну и написать код по ТЗ